# Plotting Dengue Infection Prevalence Sensitivity to Biting Rate Variations

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, visualization, systems-biology

I want to explore how varying values of the biting rate affect infection prevalence in humans in our modeled dengue outbreak, keeping all other parameters constant.

I provide you the code that I use to solve my initial problem

```
(*Parameters and initial conditions*)
nh = 10000;  (*Total number of hosts*)
nv = 20000;  (*Total number of vectors*)

initialConditions = {sh[0] == nh - 0.0028*nh, ih[0] == 0.0028*nh, 
   rh[0] == 0, sv[0] == nv - 0.00057*nv, iv[0] == 0.00057*nv};

parameters = {a = 1,(*Mosquito biting rate per day*)
   bv = 0.4,(*Probability of infection from an infected host to a \
susceptible vector*)
   bh = 0.4,(*Probability of infection from an infected vector to a \
susceptible host*)uv = 0.25,(*Mortality/
   recruitment rate of the vector*)
   r = 0.167  (*Recovery rate from dengue in humans*)};

(*Differential equations*)
equations = {sh'[t] == -a*bh*sh[t]*iv[t]/nh,
   ih'[t] == a*bh*sh[t]*iv[t]/nh - r*ih[t],
   rh'[t] == r*ih[t],
   sv'[t] == uv*nv - a*bv*sv[t]*ih[t]/nh - uv*sv[t], 
   iv'[t] == a*bv*sv[t]*ih[t]/nh - uv*iv[t]};

Plot[Evaluate[{ih[t]} /. solution2], {t, 0, 90}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"ih(t)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Dengue Model (Updated Version)", 
 AxesLabel -> {"Time (days)", "Number of hosts/vectors"}]
```

This is the case where $a=1$
[image]

Now I tried to define different values of $a$.

```
(* Define a range of values for parameter 'a' from 0 to 1 with a step size of 0.1 *)
aValues = Range[0, 1, 0.1];

(*Create a list of solutions for different'a' values*)
solutions = 
 Table[NDSolve[{equations, 
    initialConditions /. a -> aValue}, {ih}, {t, 0, 90}], {aValue, 
   aValues}]

(*Create a plot to visualize'ih(t)' for ten different'a' values*)
Plot[Evaluate[ih[t] /. solutions], {t, 0, 90}, 
 PlotLegends -> (ToString[#] & /@ aValues), 
 PlotLabel -> "Infection Prevalence (ih(t)) for Different 'a' Values",
  AxesLabel -> {"Time (days)", "Infection Prevalence (ih(t))"}, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, "ColorList"]]
```

However, the result is the following and it is not 10 different scenarios. What should I change?

[image]

Comment: What is `solution2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(*Parameters and initial conditions*)
nh = 10000;  (*Total number of hosts*)
nv = 20000;  (*Total number of vectors*)

initialConditions = {sh[0] == nh - 0.0028*nh, ih[0] == 0.0028*nh, 
   rh[0] == 0, sv[0] == nv - 0.00057*nv, iv[0] == 0.00057*nv};

parameters = {(*Mosquito biting rate per day*)
   bv = 0.4,(*Probability of infection from an infected host to a \
susceptible vector*)
   bh = 0.4,(*Probability of infection from an infected vector to a \
susceptible host*)uv = 0.25,(*Mortality/
   recruitment rate of the vector*)
   r = 0.167  (*Recovery rate from dengue in humans*)};

(*Differential equations*)
equations = {sh'[t] == -a*bh*sh[t]*iv[t]/nh, 
   ih'[t] == a*bh*sh[t]*iv[t]/nh - r*ih[t], rh'[t] == r*ih[t], 
   sv'[t] == uv*nv - a*bv*sv[t]*ih[t]/nh - uv*sv[t], 
   iv'[t] == a*bv*sv[t]*ih[t]/nh - uv*iv[t]};
(*Define a range of values for parameter'a' from 0 to 1 with a step \
size of 0.1*)aValues = Range[0, 1, 0.1];

(*Create a list of solutions for different'a' values*)
solutions = 
 Table[NDSolve[{equations, initialConditions}, {ih}, {t, 0, 90}], {a, 
   aValues}]

(*Create a plot to visualize'ih(t)' for ten different'a' values*)
```

Visualization

```
Plot[Evaluate[ih[t] /. solutions], {t, 0, 90}, 
 PlotLegends -> (ToString[#] & /@ aValues), 
 PlotLabel -> "Infection Prevalence (ih(t)) for Different 'a' Values",
  FrameLabel -> {"Time (days)", "Infection Prevalence (ih(t))"}, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, "ColorList"], PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thank you very much sir

Comment: You are welcome!